# Create a new line after a string with space and comma in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file which contains some simple strings like

```
StatusInfoSet (2, 12), StatusInfoSet (2, 44)
```

I would like delete any empty line in the file and rewrite it in below pattern to the same file as well as printing it.

```
StatusInfoSet (2, 12) 
StatusInfoSet (2, 44)
```

I forgot to add that my data too has some string like (not all contain brackets)

```
 Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello
```

Any guidance would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If strings in file is such consistent, you can simply use Python's native [replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method and write to output something like

```
original_string.replace('), ', ')\n')
```

Comment: I edited my question as I too have data which has no brackets

Comment: This worked pretty fine with a small change as `line = line.replace('), ', ')\n')
       line = line.replace('o, ', 'o\n')`

Answer (score 0):

```
,\s(?![^(]*\))
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/15

```
x="StatusInfoSet (2, 12), StatusInfoSet (2, 44)"
import re
re.sub(r",\s(?![^(]*\))","\n",x)
```